Best way to let the users know there's more content when scrollbars are not visible?
I'm working on a media player for web which features a list of audio tracks. Sometimes the number of tracks occupies more space than its available.
Usually scrollbars would help users indicate there are more tracks but in some OS scrollbars are hidden by default. It seems it's becoming impossible to force scrollbars to be visible as browsers are ignoring overflow-y: scroll;.
Is there a consensus or research on the best solution for this situation?
As much as I hate it, it seems the only solution is to create a custom scrollbar.

This article describes the topic, explaining the most common problems and providing solutions, among which are:

Add strong affordances (directional cues like arrows)
Reduce the gaps if they are too large.
Avoid unanticipated full width separators or patches
Use partially visible elements
...

I don't like any of the options 100% either, but it all depends on the design and the type of user the page is aimed at. For a user not familiar with interfaces, the arrow is the most appropriate. I lean towards more graphical solutions, such as "partially visible elements".
For example, using a bottom area that blurs part of the visible content. (See this answer on Stackoverflow). But it all depends on the design.

Thanks. Unfortunately the article talks about full pages and my issue is with a UI widget.
